# Magento php wrong version detected

Tags: magento2, php

I work in ubuntu 14 server. The problem is that in the console i see the version of my php is 7.0.14, and in the magento2 setup it says my version is 5.5.9

I appreciate any help

Comment: have you checked by echoing php_info();  function ? it gives all the detalis of php of the server

Comment: Where i put that function, i tried in /var/www/html/index.php and don't see nothing

Comment: Please go to CLI & navigate to Magento Root Directory & Run `php -v`

Comment: create one file test.php in /var/www/html/magento2/ directory  and put phpinfo(); this in it and run that file in url. check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the environment variable. Execute these commands :

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```